# How to Read input from a text file using Multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

My file name is input.txt having data

```
PTPCNPHI-NT4015 
PTPCBPHI-NT4016
PTPCBPHI-NT4017
PTPCBPHI-NT4018
...etc
```

PTPCNPHI-NT4015---is StoreName I am connecting and perform my operation(taking Backup) on single store

I want my logic has to run for all stores parallel with multiple threads

Comment: what efforts you had put to solve this problem?

Comment: how big is the file and do you have a real use case for the multithread requirement ? and what have you tried, what is not working ?

Answer (score 2):

Most often, the best approach is to **have only one thread that does the actual reading** from file, since there's little to no benefit in parallelizing the reading. Once the input is read, it can be given to a worker thread to process.

---

Depending on whether the input fits in your available memory, the multithreading part may be done in different ways:

- If the input fits in memory, you can create a [thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) then add a new task for each entry in the input. The pool will queue all inputs and fetch them to worker threads.
- If the input doesn't fit in memory, [Producer-Consumer](http://javarevisited.blogspot.cz/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html) approach may be appropriate, where the producer is the single thread "producing" the inputs based on file content, and there are multiple consumers processing the inputs.

Comment: OK ..i got your point .Is there any other way to fix the problem . I have an idea : Read entire file and keep it in a data structure (thread safe DS) then i will apply multiple threads to run on it.

Comment: I added a part about how I would do the multithreading. What you wrote is one possible approach, and it should work if input fits in your available memory. Anyway, the main point is that it's most often a good idea to read the file in one thread and only do the subsequent processing in multiple threads - and your comment already adheres to this advice.